# How to select a radio button using accordion using angular material

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-material, accordion

Hi I am trying to loop through an array with an accordion but I want a user to select a value using a radio button. I have added the radio button to it but I want a logic to uncheck all button when a check any button.

I came up with this logic but then I am not able to select other radio buttons

```
onChange(event) {
    if (event.source.id) {
        event.source.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Can someone please help me?

```
     <mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let dialog of dialogInfo let i = index" hideToggle="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-radio-group >
        <mat-radio-button (change)="onChange($event)" [name]=i [id]=i [value]="dialog">
          <mat-panel-title>{{dialog.lineone}}{{selected}}</mat-panel-title>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-list-item>{{dialog.city}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-list-item>{{dialog.state}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-list-item>{{dialog.zip}}-{{dialog.linetwo}}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue because I was wrapping the radio button in a group

This worked

```
 <mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let dialog of dialogInfo let i = index" hideToggle="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-radio-button (change)="onChange($event)" [name]=i [id]=i [value]="dialog">
          <mat-panel-title>{{dialog.lineone}}{{selected}}</mat-panel-title>
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-list-item>{{dialog.city}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-list-item>{{dialog.state}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-list-item>{{dialog.zip}}-{{dialog.linetwo}}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to stackblitz or share insight into this question. It would help me very much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209830/accordion-not-working-as-expected-in-angular